# Have different permalinks based on category

Tags: categories, permalinks

I am building my blog, but I want the permalinks to have different structure depending on the categories.

Example: `cat1` and `cat2` are blogs and the permalink should be:

```
domain.com/postname
```

with my `cat3` are blog post, but identified differently so should be

```
domain.com/customslugforcat3/postname
```

Same with my `cat4`:

```
domain.com/customslugforcat4/postname
```

Is this possible? If so then how?

Comment: Are the posts interchangeable? What differentiates `cat1` and `cat2`? Is it necessary to use categories?

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind with questions like these is: Why? You use the word "blog" and "blogs" to describe various different things. A category is not a blog, so when you say that cat1 and cat2 are blogs, then what do you mean exactly?

Comment: You may want to look into custom post types rather than just using Posts. Each CPT can have its own permalink structure, defined when you create it.

Comment: @WebElaine that was exactly my thought as well, but maybe `cat1` and `cat2` doesn't need to be custom post types, those can be categories.

Comment: Perhaps a custom taxonomy would work then. It's hard to say without knowing more of the context.